# Automate the read and save of several json files (with different information) to different pandas dataframes

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have several json files in a folder, each one with different shapes (number of lines and columns) and information.

I have the following code to open and save a json file to a pandas df:

```
with open('f_fruit.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

df_fruit = pd.DataFrame(data['fruit'])
```

In the end, I would like to have different pandas dataframes, one for each json file:

```
df_fruit

df_clothes

df_games
```

What is the best way to automate this code, considering that the files names and information do not follow a pattern? Is it possible?

Comment: You may want to consider using a dictionary where the keys are the data frame names and the values are the data frames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your files are named following the same logic I would do the following:

```
files = ['f_fruit.json','f_clothes.json','f_games.json'] #you can use os.walk to get a list of files from a specific folder

for file_name in files:
    col_name = file_name.split('.')[0][2:]
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    var_name = 'df_{}'.format(col_name)
    globals()[var_name] = pd.DataFrame(data[col_name])
```

However, if

> files names and information do not follow a pattern

then there is no easy way to automate this. You need a pattern.

Here the part you are probably interested in, i.e. how to create a variable from a value already in memory using `globals()`.

```
>>> col_name = 'fruit'
>>> var_name = 'df_{}'.format(col_name)
>>> globals()[var_name] = 'some value'
>>> df_fruit
'some value'
```

Comment: It almost work.. I received the following error: File "<ipython-input-84-23127bc62561>", line 8
    globals()[f'df_{var_name}'] = pd.DataFrame(data[var_name])
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: What is the version of your Python?

Comment: I use Python 2.

Comment: @Thabra Try now.

Comment: Thanks! I got an error due to the last line: ----> 9     globals()[var_name] = pd.DataFrame(data[col_name])

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: What is col_name? Try to print it. My code works, it must be something with the dataframe. Are you sure that `pd.DataFrame(data['fruit'])` works as expected?